# ¿Cómo agregar comillas simples a una variable en js?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una función que recibe dos variables js, la primera es un número y la segunda es un texto. Aca está mi problema ¿cómo le agrego al valor de esta variable comillas simple?

Ejemplo

```
var id = "2"
var cliente = "cliente 2"

Reagendar(id,cliente)
```

Lo que me sale es `Reagendar(2,cliente 2)` sin comillas simples.

Lo que necesito es que salga asi `Reagendar(2,'cliente 2')`.

Ya intente con `json.stringfy` pero me agrega con comillas dobles y necesito que sea comilla simple.

Les paso esa parte del código:

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="Ragendar('+value.id_nota_diaria+','+value.cliente +');">Re-Agendar</a></li>
```

Comment: posiblemente ninguna respuesta te sirva porque no has proporcionado los detalles esenciales de tu problema, te recomiendo poner un [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

al recibir en javascript puedes hacer la conversion en el formato deseado
ejemplo:

```
var id = 2;
var cliente = "cliente 2"
var paramentroFinal=id+","+"'"+cliente+"'";
alert(parametroFinal);
//output
//2 ,'cliente 2'
```

espero te sirva .. suerte !!

Comment: gracias amigo si funciono,una salida rapida no se me habia ocurrido xD gracias

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes hacer de varias formas:

1ª: como te indican; escapando el caracter: var cliente: "/'cliente 2 /'";

2ª concatenando cadeanas:  var res = "'" + "cliente2" + "'";

Answer (score -1):

Puedes lograrlo utilizando string interpolation (ES6)

```
var id = "2"
var cliente = "cliente 2"

Reagendar(id, `'${cliente}'`);
```